# Why PHP generated HTML is rendered with glitch?

Tags: php, html, css

My problem is that php generated html content differs from the hard-coded one, while they are absolutely the same. This picture shows the wrong behavior, as said, generated by a function.

[image]

As you can see, the tabs are overlapping. Now, if I look at the generated source code (via Firebug in Firefox, or directly in the page source), and simply copy and paste it manually in the page, the result is this (the desired one):

[image]

The same result is presented in Chrome, IE and FF (all for Windows, but I guess in other OS is the same as well).

This is the generated code (copy/paste from the generated source):

```
                 <ul>
                    <li><span data-link="/">Pagina principala</span></li>
                    <li><span data-link="/piscine">Piscine</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span data-link="/piscine/piscine-rezidentiale">Piscine rezidentiale</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/piscine/piscine-publice">Piscine publice</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span data-link="/spa">Spa</span></li>
                    <li><span data-link="/saune">Saune</span></li>
                    <li><span data-link="/wellness">Wellness</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/sauna">Sauna</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/spa">Spa</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/baia-de-aburi">Baia de aburi</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/infracabine">Infracabine</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/solarii">Solarii</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/dusuri">Dusuri</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/wellness/fantana-de-gheata">Fantana de gheata</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span data-link="/aquaparcuri">Aquaparcuri</span>
                        <ul>
                            <li><span data-link="/aquaparcuri/tobogane">Tobogane</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/aquaparcuri/jocuri-acvatice">Jocuri acvatice</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/aquaparcuri/tobogane-copii">Tobogane copii</span></li>
                            <li><span data-link="/aquaparcuri/atractii-de-apa">Atractii de apa</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><span data-link="/irigatii">Irigatii</span></li>
                    <li><span data-link="#">Galerie foto</span></li>
                    <li><span data-link="#">Contact</span></li>
                </ul>
```

No weird characters, no extra characters, no inline style applied. I don't understand this behavior. The css rules are the same. Tried to put the generated html in a temporary db table, then read it from there. Also tried to put into a file, and read it back. The result is the same (as in the first picture) all the time, expect if I manually put that list in the page. Why?

These two functions are generating the the html

```
function return_middle_menu() {
   $item = '';
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `category_top` WHERE `active` = 1 ORDER BY `sort`");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $cat_number = $row['id'];
    $sub_menu = return_middle_menu_sub($cat_number);
    if ($sub_menu != '') { $sub_menu = '<ul>'.$sub_menu.'</ul>'; }
    $temp_name = strtolower($row['name']); $temp_name = ucfirst($temp_name);
    $temp_link = $row['page_link'];
    $temp_link = str_replace($row['name'], $temp_name, $temp_link);
    $temp_link = str_replace('<a ', '<span ', $temp_link);
    $temp_link = str_replace('</a>', '</span>', $temp_link);
    $item .= '<li>'.str_replace('href', 'data-link', $temp_link).$sub_menu.'</li>';
}
return $item;
}

function return_middle_menu_sub($cat_number) {
$item = '';
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `sub_category_top` WHERE `active` = 1 AND `cat_number` = $cat_number ORDER BY `sort`");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows >= 1) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $temp_name = strtolower($row['name']); $temp_name = ucfirst($temp_name);
        $temp_link = $row['page_link'];
        $temp_link = str_replace($row['name'], $temp_name, $temp_link);
        $temp_link = str_replace('<a ', '<span ', $temp_link);
        $temp_link = str_replace('</a>', '</span>', $temp_link);
        $item .= '<li>'.str_replace('href', 'data-link', $temp_link).'</li>';
    }
}
return $item;
}
```

And the applied `CSS` rules are here

```
    .middle_menu { background: #a29f9f; min-height: 25px; padding: 10px 5px 0; }
    .middle_menu ul {
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    .middle_menu ul li {
        font-family: 'SegoeUI-SemiBold', Segoe UI, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #00334d;
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: -2px;
        position: relative;
        padding: 7px 30px 7px 39px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
        -o-transition: all 0.2s;
        transition: all 0.2s;
    }
    .middle_menu > ul > li {
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), -ms-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), -moz-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), -o-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #E6E6E6), color-stop(1, #FEFEFE));
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #E6E6E6 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
        background-image: url(../img/menu_triangle.png), linear-gradient(to bottom, #E6E6E6 0%, #FEFEFE 100%);
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px !important; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px !important; -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px !important; -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px !important; border-top-left-radius: 5px !important; border-top-right-radius: 5px !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-y;
        background-position: 13px center, top left;
    }
    .middle_menu ul li:hover {
        background: #555;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .middle_menu ul li ul {
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 36px;
        left: 0;
        width: 200px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
        -transition: opacity 0.2s;
    }
    .middle_menu ul li ul li {
        background: #555;
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
        padding: 7px 10px;
    }
    .middle_menu ul li ul li:hover { background: #666; }
    .middle_menu ul li ul li a:hover { background: #666; }
    .middle_menu ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        z-index: 9;
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking at the *source code*, or the "element inspector"? Make sure you're checking the difference at the raw source code level, not at the processed DOM level. Also, anything else different? Especially HTML doctype declarations and/or HTTP headers?

Comment: also, could we see the generation code in php?

Comment: Updated the original post with the PHP code.

Comment: @deceze The doctype is HTML5, and beside that the generated html is not indented, I can't see anything different. Thanks for tip tho, I'll keep in mind for future investigations.

Comment: Something to do with some of your CSS rules; if you're using CSS? You're using `str_replace()` for a few things.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sure I use some rules, but if I `echo` out something, or simply write it, the applied style shouldn't be the same?! Anyway, I'll edit my post to put the css rules as well. Thank you.

Comment: Probably not just indentation, but *whitespace* may be missing between elements, no? This may make some difference, depending on your CSS rules and whether elements are inline or blocks.

Comment: To simplify a bit, http://www.shopcontent.ro/ here is a link where you can see it in action.. The upper tab bar is copy/pasted from what the php generated, while the lower one is the direct php echo..

Comment: @Fred-ii- I use `str_replace()` only to change the `a` tags to `span` tags, and to switch the `href` to a `data attribute`. That's all.

Comment: @deceze You were right, but I can't imagine why this happening. Upvoted your comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like already stated in the comments, the reason is definitely the lack of whitespaces and/or linebreaks in your php output.
Most likely this produces problems in connection with your `:before` and `:after` (speudo-)selectors in CSS, since they usually apply to the characters between the tags.
If you just insert some whitespaces and/or linebreaks (for example changing the `'</li>'` to `'</li> '` or `'</li> ' . PHP_EOL`) after the closing tags, the problem shouldn't occur anymore.

Comment: I've inserted everywhere a space, `before` and `after` opening/closing tags, and indeed, the problem is solved. Who would have thought.. Thanks again for deceze, who led to the correct answer. Thanks everyone.